# Query Firebase based on field and return parent in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to search through my Firebase database and find a field:value pairing that matches my query, and then return either that parent's key, or the parent object so that I may grab other information as well.

The Firebase database looks something like this:

```
Events{
  -KiXlIGhB6k-HpCKfO3n{
    name:"Breakfast at Tiffany's",
    owner:"Tim",
    startTime:{
      startHour:1,
      startMinute:30
    },
    ...
  },
  -dFgfh8Efa-Hpwe6Goqp0{...}
}
```

I'm currently attempting:

```
public void importSchedule(String ownerName){
DatabaseReference events = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events"); //Inside the Events list

Query allOwnersEvents = events.equalTo(ownerName); //Find events equalTo ownerName provided

allOwnersEvents.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           // This is where the parent's could be queried, all events belonging to an "owner" should be cycled through
        }
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

However when placing a break-point inside the for loop, it is never triggered. I'm wondering if I'm attempting the query correctly or if there's an easier way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never triggered because your `DatabaseReference` is wrong. When you query, you are missing a child. In order to have the correct `DatabaseReference` please use this code:

```
    DatabaseReference events = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events")
    events.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String eventKey = ds.getKey(); //parent key

            DatabaseReference allOwnersEvents = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events").child(eventKey);
            allOwnersEvents.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String ownerName = dataSnapshot.child("ownerName").getValue(String.class); //do what you want with ownerName
                }
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
        }
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

In which `eventId` is the unique id generated by the `push()` method. Hope it helps.

Comment: What if I'm looking through all the events (not just the one specified by the eventID). I'm trying to get all the events that have the ownerName inside of them

Comment: So this is for all your events, not for a single one. Because `eventId` it's a variable and not a single value. If i have used in your code, let's say `child("-KiXlIGhB6k-HpCKfO3n")` than is was only for a single event. But this works for all your events.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you, but you're saying that `child(eventID)` will query all my Events? And store the unique key in the eventID variable? Or are you saying that `child("-KiXlIGhB6k-HpCKfO3n")` will just query the one child. In this scenario, I'm assuming I don't have the IDs of the events I'm trying to query

Comment: Please see my updated answer in which you have also the `parent key`.

Comment: In the updated answer `dataSnapshot.getKey();` returns the parent's key again, so it ends up looking for `https://mydata.firebaseio.com/Events/Events` rather than `https://mydata.firebaseio.com/Events/-KiXlIGhB6k-HpCKfO3n`, but I see where you're going with it - Do you need to grab that key every-time?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I forgot to add a loop. Now it should work.

Comment: the `onDataChange()` isn't called when the method is initialized, and when I do add a value to the database in order for the event Listener to be triggered, it returns `String ownerName = null` maybe due to the query missing? Is it possible to grab the whole object and go through the elements?

Comment: Yes because i used in a wrong way `String eventKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();` in stead of `String eventKey = ds.getKey();`. Updated my answer again.

Comment: Yes, because of the `ds`. See my above commnet and updated answer.

Comment: Grabs it perfectly now! Thanks! Would you perchance happen to know why the onDataChange isn't being called when I first assign the Listener?

Comment: Happy to head that and glad to help. `onDataChange` was called but on the wrong `reference`. If you think that my answer helped you, consider giving me and a +1. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the complete answer??  Why are you posting just a section of code that fixes one section of the original code?   How am I supposed to know exactly what section you are replacing??  Telepathy??  Using the accepted answer just on it's own I am left with String ownerName = dataSnapshot.child("ownerName").getValue(String.class);  which means nothing without any of the surrounding context.   Wish people would stop doing this.