# Firebase search child and return parent key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to return the UID key value in Firebase from a search on its child parameters.

```
-Users

 -BCsuC4XAZq0MDK1taLcD2
      -Name: Test1
      -Phone:  0011223344


 -t50GPKxb8mgINGbmGJrR83
      -Name: Test2
      -Phone: 9988776655
```

So from this database above, I am trying to implement a search function based on the phone number, where a user searching for "9988776655" will get the return value of "t50GPKxb8mgINGbmGJrR83", but after hours of messing about I am no closer to being able to do this.

There is a post here:
[Query Firebase based on field and return parent in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618268/query-firebase-based-on-field-and-return-parent-in-android)
That looks like it would be pretty close, but unfortunately the full solution code is not offered.  After dabbling around with it, the best I can get trying to fit it into my scenario is a null response.

Does anyone have any idea how I can actually do this?   I have read dozens of forum posts, and watched several youtube tutorials but no one seems to be able to do this.   Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
 ref.orderByChild("Phone").equalTo(9988776655).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
   for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String keys=datas.getKey();
  }

 @Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


    }
   });
```

Using the above, you will be on the datasnapshot `Users`, then since you want to search based on the phone number, you can do this `orderByChild("Phone").equalTo(9988776655)` which will search the phone number that is equal to the value provided. The value can be a variable that you add there or a string `"9988776655"`.

Then to be able to get the random id, you need to iterate inside the direct children, using `getKey()` you will be able to retrieve the random id of the phone that is equal to 9988776655

Comment: Thank you for your response, Peter.   I tried this out and it does not work.   I used toast at each line to step this through, and it never executes anything at all after this section of code:   for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {  anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what did you write here `orderByChild("Phone").equalTo(9988776655)`? Also is `Users` a child under the root node? @Bisclavret

Comment: It works!  I was using a variable instead of the specific string value for 9988776655.  I had tried to get the string from an EditText onCreate, like an idiot, so that when the string is populated it becomes null immediately.   Sorry Peter, your answer was spot on.