# how to search multiple nodes for a specific string value, and then get the key holding that value?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

So for context, I have this string called time, and it has a value saved in one the nodes on my database. What I want to do is find what node/key is holding the value of that time string.

See picture:
[Screenshot of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twSv0.png)

Essentially I want to search my database and find out which node is holding the value of this time string. and after finding which node, I need to get its push key ID and save it on a string variable.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: @f1sh my bad on that, I meant only java and android studio

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905467/firebase-search-child-and-return-parent-key

Comment: @f1sh how do I get reference if the child value is a push key?

Comment: @f1sh the second link you gave, is indeed what im looking for, but somehow it does not work.

Comment: Im sorry my bad, It worked! thankyou so much for you help @f1sh